# typescript extract record from union

Tags: typescript

i have this union of records

```
type PhysicalEntry = Record<
    'color' | 'luster' | 'name' | 'quantity' | 'status' | 'type',
    {
      value: string | number
      hasCheck: boolean
      readOnly: boolean
    }
  > &
    Record<
      'customData',
      {
        values: Array<number>
        hasCheck: boolean
        readOnly: boolean
      }
    >
```

how do i extract the first record by excluding `PhysicalEntry['customData']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Omit helper type.

```
type WithoutCustomData = Omit<PhysicalEntry, "customData">
```

TypeScript will expand the rest of the properties, but the shape will be correct.

Comment: I think, using `Pick` would be more semantically here